# Зайдет ли useEffect в рекурсию, если внутре него изменить его же зависимость?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
 useEffect(() => {
        if (!isLoading) {
            return
        }

        (async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('/api/auth/register', options)
                setData(await response.json())
                console.log(response)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } finally {
                setIsLoading(false)
            }
        })()
    }, [isLoading, url, options])
```

Comment: В каком месте у вас рекурсия? Я её не вижу, просто асинхронная функция. А вообще проверить элементарно запустив код и вы увидите результат.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вы неправильно понимаете как работает `useEffect`.

Из документации:

> По умолчанию эффекты запускаются после каждого завершённого рендера.
>   Таким образом, эффект всегда пересоздаётся, если значение какой-то из
>   зависимости изменилось.

Тут внимание на ключевое слово **пересоздаётся**. То, что вы написали это не рекурсия во-первых. Как написано наверху, `useEffect` всегда пересоздаётся, (а не заходит в рекурсию) если хоть одна из его зависимостей изменилась.